# Passing Pointers to a function?

Tags: c++

Why is this code not valid?

```
void callbyreference (int& adam) {
    cout << adam << endl;
}

int main() {
    int *beta = new int();
    *beta = 34;
    callbyreference(beta);
}
```

Comment: because a reference is not a pointer.

Comment: Because you're passing an `int*` as an `int`. Try `callbyreference(*beta)`

Comment: Look beta is a pointer (memory address). And int &adam takes in a memory address. Shouldn't it work?

Comment: @John.J.Adams `int& adam` is not an address, it's a reference. Don't confuse a type with one of its possible representations.

Answer (score 2):

Because `beta` is a pointer to `int`, but `callbyreference` doesn't take a pointer parameter - it takes a reference.
References are not pointers.

You can say either

```
void callbyreference (int* adam) {
    cout << *adam << endl;
}

int main() {
    int *beta = new int();
    *beta = 34;
    callbyreference(beta);
}
```

or

```
void callbyreference (int& adam) {
    cout << adam << endl;
}

int main() {
    int beta = 34;
    callbyreference(beta);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
void callbyreference (int& adam) {
    cout << adam << endl;
}

int main() {
   int *beta = new int();
   *beta = 34;
   callbyreference(*beta);
}
```

Comment: Please explain your answer and take into account that markup commands (e.g. `**` do not function in code sections.):